# Distinct High Level Rest Client Elastic Query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

How to use `High Level Rest Client` to find documents by distinct value. Documentation talks about `Aggregation framework` for finding distinct `documents` by `field`. But I could not find any example using `High Level Rest Client`. How can I get distinct `documents` by `field`.

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("Field1", "Value1"))
searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);

searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(????)
```

Data

```
{
    ..
    ..

      "Field1" : "Value1",
      "Field2" : "Value2"
    },
    {
      "Field1" : "Value1",
      "Field2" : "Value21"
    }
}
```

Expected Output (any document with "Field1" : "Value1")

```
{
    ..
    ..

      "Field1" : "Value1",
      "Field2" : "Value2"
    }
}
```

[Elastic Search Query for Distinct Nested Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888164/elastic-search-query-for-distinct-nested-values)

[Elastic Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

**Code below gives the same result:**

```
   AggregationBuilder termAggregationBuilder = AggregationBuilders
                .terms("someName")
                .field("Field1");
   AggregationBuilder topHitsAggregationBuilder = AggregationBuilders
                .topHits("someOtherName")
                .fetchSource(includeFields, excludeFields);
   searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(termAggregationBuilder.subAggregation(topHitsAggregationBuilder));
```

Comment: Can you add sample docs and expected output to make the question more clear?

Comment: @NishantSaini Added link

Comment: You need to use [TermsAggregationBuilder](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-aggregation-builders.html#_bucket_aggregations)

Comment: @NishantSaini  Can you please elaborate on how to use it. I tried using TermsAggregationBuilder and TopHits